# Php Vs Java String Comparison from database

Tags: java, php, mysql, arrays, string-comparison

So, say I have 500 strings like:

- `<script>something here</script>`
- `get_magic_quotes_gpc(`
  ...

Say these strings are stored in a database(mysql)

Is Java or Php typically faster for recursively going through directories, subdirectories and finding a string provided by a database?

Could both be equally as fast (based on the quality of the code written) ?

I've been trying to look into it, it seems java is quicker, but could php equally as fast if say the strings are stored in a local array instead (and not in a database)?

I'm not trying to create a java vs php war here, but I would like some evidence if one is faster than the other, or if both can be for the most part equally as fast (based on the code written) ?

Thanks

Comment: for very I/O bound tasks, like reading from a db and looking recursively for files the differences in performance between PHP and Java are likely not to matter much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at here is called premature optimization.  Don't do it.  Pick whichever language you know best (or works best for your current project) and go from there.

Further reading:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Comment: Thanks for this, #newbie mistake!